# How to change font color of GridView?

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have tried adding a table class and change the color from there but it doesn't work. Here is my widget:

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'options' => [
              'class' => 'CustomTableClass',
         ],

    'columns' => [
        'Contract_id',
        'Contract_title',
        'Description',
        'Contract_type',
        'Contract_provider',
        'Effective_date',
        'Expiration_date',
        'Status_id',

    ],
]); ?>
```

Here's my class:

```
.CustomClass table thead {
   color: #ffffff;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong name. In you css you have `CustomClass`  but in options you have `CustomTableClass`

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'options' => [
              'class' => 'CustomClass',
         ],

    'columns' => [
        'Contract_id',
        'Contract_title',
        'Description',
        'Contract_type',
        'Contract_provider',
        'Effective_date',
        'Expiration_date',
        'Status_id',

    ],
]); ?>
```

but in your case you are trying to change an header css style and you could use

```
.CustomHeadClass {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

.

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'headerRowOptions' => [
              'class' => 'CustomHeadClass ',
         ],

    'columns' => [
        'Contract_id',
        'Contract_title',
        'Description',
        'Contract_type',
        'Contract_provider',
        'Effective_date',
        'Expiration_date',
        'Status_id',

    ],
]); ?>
```